# How do I pass a function pointer to a contract method from a unit test?

Tags: truffle-test, function-pointer

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: invalid type (arg="type", value="function")
```

when trying to call this method on the contract `IntOption`:

```
function create(
    address target,
    string memory name,
    int initialValue,
    function (address, string memory, int) external view validate
) public {
```

from my unit test. I'm trying to pass this function defined in `Config4AccessControl` as argument for `validate`:

```
function anyValue(address, string memory, int value) public pure {
    // any value is ok
}
```

This is the unit test:

```
it("should not be defined after it's created", async () => {
    const intOptions = await IntOption.new();
    const ac = await Config4AccessControl.new();
    await intOptions.create(addr1, 'foo', 1, ac.anyValue.address);
```

Comment: I believe that the function pointer must be to an internal function (though the fact that you haven't reported any compilation error implies that I'm wrong here).

Comment: I was surprised as well but you can a) define function pointers with the syntax above and then pass any matching method from any visible (imported) contract.

Comment: That it compiles doesn't mean it is supported. I see no reference to function pointers in Solidity's ABI.

Comment: @Ismael The documentation mentions them: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html#function-types "function parameters of function type can be used to pass functions to and return functions from function calls."

Comment: @AaronDigulla The docs says that an external function is encoded as bytes24: address + selector. It seems web3 doesn't have support for them unfortunately.

Comment: @Ismael So I need to open a bug report against web3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be supported by web3 (at the time of writing: 1.2.4): https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2826